# log4j.xml path problem

Tags: log4j

I am trying to get log4j working using xml configuration. I have log4j.xml added to classpath but while running I am getting :

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (test.DateFormatter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

If I place a log4j.properties instead it seems to pick up the configuration.
Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to have a log4j.xml in the classpath but it also has to provide the correct configuration. So maybe you post the content of your log4j.xml file so we can help you (maybe typo in logger configuration?).

You should also have a look at the [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) manual. The section "Default Initialization Procedure" describes how log4j will try to find the initialization file.